# Variable is null when used within same class context

Tags: php, class, oop, object

Writing up a class for debugging data which debugs directly to SQL, also a class. The Debug and MySQLConnection classes have worked fine until I tried to implement SQL error reporting using the Debug class the other day.

The plan is that if an error occurs during SQL execution, the MySQL class reports back to Debug which then formats it for input into the databse using the MySQL class. The errors it would input would be where the connection succeeds.

So what I've got is as follows:

```
<?php

class Debug
{
    private $MySQL

    function __construct()
    {
        #Pass the debug object to MySQL in case we need to report errors
        $this->MySQL = new MySQLConnection($this);
    }

    public function DebugMessage($message,$code,$typeid,$SQLObj = null)
    {
        $InsertArray = array(
            #Some data, takes into account the arguments for this function
        );

        #Connect to the database and insert the data. If the connection fails, false will be returned and handled by caller. If true, everything went as planned.
        return $this->MySQL->insert('debugproc',$InsertArray);

    }
}

class MySQLConnection extends MySQLConfiguration
{
    #MySQLConfiguration is just a class containing the connection information in a protected format

    private $Debugger;
    private $SQLConn;

    function __construct($Debug)
    {
        $this->Debugger = $Debug;
    }

    public function connect()
    {
        try
        {
#This is where I get the details from the global config.
            $this->SQLConn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . config['db']['host'] . ";dbname=" . config['db']['dbname'], config['db']['user'], config['db']['pass']);
            return true;
        }
        catch (PDOException $pdo)
        {
            echo $pdo->getMessage();
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function insert($query,$data)
    {
        if($this->connect())
        {
            try
            {
                #Prepare our insert using the MySQLConfiguration array. This stores the SQL queries.
                $prepare = $this->SQLConn->prepare($this->MySQLConfiguration[$query]);
                $result = $prepare->execute($data);
                if(!$result)
                {
                    echo "Failed to insert";
                    return false;
                }
                #Release resources and disconnect from SQL
                unset($prepare);
                $this->disconnect();
            }
            catch(PDOException $pdo)
            {
                echo $pdo->getMessage();
            }

        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }

    }
}

?>
```

So basically, what I'm seeing is when I construct Debug, a call is made to MySQL which contains $this, the Debug object. After that, it just awaits DebugMessage calls. When one arrives, a call *should* be made to $this->MySQL (MySQLConnection) to insert the relevant data. Since I can't var_dump on $this->MySQL through __construct, I echoed when the connections occur and this does happen and the connection is made successfully. As the connection is made, we should be seeing $this->MySQL's object in DebugMessage but this isn't the case, this is actually NULL!

I thought it was perhaps a visibility issue but on setting $MySQL in Debug context to public, that still showed the object as NULL during DebugMessage.

You got any ideas on this one?

Comment: What's the sample usage of this classes?

Comment: This is called by a wrapper which controls output to different devices, for now, just into a JS array. There is one debug object which is passed around all objects made for that particular wrapper. 

This isn't done in the case for the relationship between MySQL and Debug though as this needs it's own object here.

UPDATE: I just tested an insert through MySQLConnection instantiation and found this did update the table showing Debug is calling this properly.

Comment: I'm now wondering if this is a hierarchical issue instead since we are passing debug to MySQLConnection then allowing MySQLConnection to pass back to what is effectively itself...

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue here to be some error handling in the MySQL object from a previous iteration. The calls went back to DebugMessage before the connection had been made and, as such, gave a null error on MySQL in the Debug context.

Commenting the calls to DebugMessage resolved the null variable issues.

What it all boiled down to was a connection which was diconnected. When disconnecting, the variable is set to null in MySQLConnection's context. When this was null, DebugMessage was getting fired before the connection was performed.

DOH!